# Bind click event to all elements except two

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a menu and a button to toggle this menu:

```
<a id="openMenu" onclick="openMenu()">Menu</a>
<div class="menu">..menu stuff..</div>
```

Now I want to bind a click event on the whole `<body>`, except the two described elements. The click event is, that when the `<menu>` is visible and the user clicks anywhere inside the `<body>` the `<menu>` should close again.

I have the following code for this:

```js
var menuComponents = $(".menu, #openMenu").children();
  $("body")
    .not(menuComponents)
    .on("mousedown", function (event) {
      if ($(".menu").attr("active") == "true") {
        setActive(".menu");
      }
    });
```

But now when the `menu` is opened and I click on the `<a id="openMenu"...>` button to close the `menu` again, it is closed and immediately opened again. So, is it possible to exclude the `menu` and `openMenu` button from the body?

Are there any hints on why this behavior is so?

Comment: How about catching the click at the two elements and preventing bubbling?

Comment: Define your `openMenu` function outside and try adding `event.preventDefault()` inside it. Since its <a> element I believe it refreshes the page and thats why u see such behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listener to `body` then if the clicked element (`e.target`) is the link `.toggle()` the menu -- otherwise any other click will default to closing the menu.

BTW, there are some things you shouldn't do (especially if you use jQuery).

- [Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these), so don't use them.
- `#id` just hinder your ability to update and expand your code, so use classes. There are a few times when `#id` might be necessary but no with the present situation.

  ```
   <a /*id*/="useClassNotID" /*onclick="DoNotUse(this)"*/>Menu</a>
  ```

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('.openMenu')) {
    $('.menu').toggle({
      duration: 500
    });
  } else {
    $('.menu').hide({
      duration: 500
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<a href='#' class="openMenu">Menu</a>
<section class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and hints for using jQuery! It worked.